# Copy over data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an open workbook that has a bunch of macros in it, one of these macros is to copy data from this workbook and paste it into another workbook on a server. So far I can open the server workbook, and navigate to the right tab and cell but I cannot paste the data... My code is below:

```
Sub aggregate()
    Dim m As String
    Dim t As Integer

    'opened workbook
    Sheets("Month Count").Select
    range("A2").Select

    Do
        m = ActiveCell.Value
        t = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("\\LOCATIONOFOTHERWORKBOOKONSERVER")
        xl.Visible = True

        xlwbook.Worksheets("A").range("A2").Select
        xlwbook.ActiveCell.Value = m **this is where my code breaks.**
        xlwbook.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = t

        'HOW TO SAVE FILE AND CLOSE FILE?    

        Windows("GOBACKTOFIRSTWORKBOOK").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "THE END"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you realize that the second character of the line where you say your code breaks is a 1 (number), not an L (letter)?

Comment: thanks, yeah its like that in the question but not in my code. It still does not work...

Comment: Does it break the first time through the loop or does it work once and then break the second time (because you aren't closing the workbook on the server)? Also, why are you creating a new `Excel.Application` when you could open the server workbook in the same application object as the first workbook?

Comment: it doesn't complete the first loop, it cant get past x1wbook.worksheets("Month Count").activecell.value = mon. As for why im creating a new excel.application, it is because the line x1.visible = true breaks without that first creatobject.. im not very proficient in vba... just enough to get by...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like below which will find a range from A2 to a cell contain "THE END" in column A of a sheet called "Month Count" in the ActiveWorbook, then open a second workbook ( I used `C:\test\other.xlsm"`, goto sheet "A", and then put

- A2 from the first book into A2 of the second book,
- B2 from the first book into A3 in the second book,
- A3 from the first book into A4 in the second book,
- B3 from the first book into A5 in the second book etc

Note that in your code you are currently opening a new Excel instance, you should work on both workbooks in the same instance so that they can "talk"

```
Sub aggregate()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCalc As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    lngCalc = .Calculation
End With

Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = Wb1.Sheets("Month Count")
Set rng1 = ws1.Columns("A").Find("THE END", , xlValues, xlWhole)

If rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Did not find marker cell"
    GoTo QuickExit
End If

Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a2], ws1.Cells(rng1.Row, "A"))
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\other.xlsm")
Set ws2 = Wb2.Sheets("A")
For Each rng2 In rng1
    ws2.[a2].Offset(lngRow, 0) = rng2
    ws2.[a2].Offset(lngRow + 1, 0) = rng2.Offset(0, 1)
    lngRow = lngRow + 2
Next
Wb2.Save
Wb2.Close
Wb1.Activate


QuickExit:

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = lngCalc
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: wow thanks man, yours worked from the get go, just plugged it in and it did its thing! I need to mod it a little, and I don't fully understand what exactly is going on but i'll study it. thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the quick close out. :) If you data set is large then a variant array rewrite will cut the data re-organisation time down significantly, [sample here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2684.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. there is no point "activating" your workbooks.
2. you don't need to instantiate a second Excel if your macro is already running in Excel.
3. it would be much faster to do in one shot
4. I suspect your error comes from the fact `xlwbook` has not been activated when you use `xlwbook.ActiveCell`.

Below is my proposal for your copy/paste thing, the one by one way (or I should say 2 by 2).

```
    Sub aggregate2()
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Dim xlwbook As Workbook

    Set rngSource = Sheets("Month Count").Range("A2:B2")

    Set xlwbook = Workbooks.Open("\\LOCATIONOFOTHERWORKBOOKONSERVER")
    Set rngDest = xlwbook.Range("A2:B2")

    Do
        rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value
        Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until rngDest.Cells(1, 1) = "THE END"  
    xlwbook.close
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this, ill play around with it. im a vba noob... how do i enable option explicit? I don't think it can be done all in one shot because i need to do this for multiple worksheets from various sources and add totals up..

Comment: option explicit: you write it at the very top of your module. You can also set VBE option to insert that automatically for you whenever you create a new module (it's in Tools, Options, Require Variable Declaration)